# Text input with useState object child

Tags: reactjs, input, state

I have a bunch of input fields, and instead of having multiple states to manage each; I would like one state object:

```
const [myObj, setMyObj] = useState({ icon: '', name: '', something: '', another: '' })
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to update state:

```
<input 
    type='text'
    value={myObj.name}
    onChange={e => {
      let temp = myObj
      temp.name= e.target.value
      setMyObj(temp)
    }}>
</input>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't appear to update because you're doing a state-mutation. For React to re-render correctly and reflect your changes, you need to pass in a completely new state object via your state updater function.

I suppose the quickest and dirtiest way of doing this is just creating a shallow-copy of your state object by using the spread operator:

```
<input 
    type='text'
    value={myObj.name}
    onChange={e => {
      let temp = {...myObj}
      temp.name= e.target.value
      setMyObj(temp)
    }}>
</input>
```

But defining all your logic within the event-listener is really not the best way to do this.

What you should do is extract the logic into a separate event-handler like this:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
   let newState = {...myObj}
   let { name, value } = e.target
   newState[name] = value
   setMyObj(newState)
}
```

Then in your input, give it a `name` property associated with a key belonging to the state. And assign that event-listener with the event-handler.

```
<input 
    type='text'
    value={myObj.name}
    name="name"
    onChange={handleChange}>
</input>
```

Comment: Great thanks Christopher, I was planning to extract the logic given there was a solution as well but didn't think of using the name property. Very effective!